# get_post by post title always returns last inserted post

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I try to use get_post in wordpress it always returns the last post.

```
$the_code = 'couponcode';
$args = array(
  'post_title'  => 'couponcode',
  'post_type'   => 'shop_coupon',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'numberposts' => 1
);
$my_code = get_posts($args);
```

this is how I insert a coupon post:

```
$coupon = array(
    'post_title' => 'couponcode',
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_type'     => 'shop_coupon'
);

$new_coupon_id = wp_insert_post( $coupon );
```

It shows up alright in the backend admin.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. What should it return for you?

Comment: You are querying to get the last inserted one. Change "numberposts" value if you want more data

Comment: How do i return only the post that have 'couponcode' as post title. Because it returns the post that have different title. Right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this simple query.

```
$posttitle = 'testcoupon';
$coupons = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = '" . $posttitle . "' AND post_type = 'shop_coupon'" );
```

This code is tested OK

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirements you can try this

```
$coupontitle = 'couponcode';
$postid = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = '" . $coupontitle . "'" );
```

Comment: Right now it returns post that have different post title. I want it to only return the one that has 'couponcode' as post title.

Comment: if its not showing post from title then you can also create post category "couponcode" then assign your couponcode named posts under it, then pass category id or name in your args array like this cat=1 or 'category_name' => 'my-category-slug'

Comment: The coupon is made with woocommerece. I just want to get a single coupon with the exact post_title name. For some reason post_title in args doesn't work in the get_posts function. Do you have a solution to this?

Comment: then try custom query
$coupontitle = 'couponcode';
$postid = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = '" . $coupontitle . "'" );
echo $postid;